# Redis - Which datatype would be most efficient way to store data

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis

I am not exactly sure which datatype/approach would be best for given the following scenarios.

I will be storing full json objects and each of these objects will have multiple properties, one of them will be an ID (int field).

```
public class Event
{
   public int EventId {get; set}
   public DateTime EventDate {get; set;}
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public int TypeId {get; set;}
}
```

1. I will need to be able to look up individual objects by this id, I assume this will be just be stored as a key/value pair, key being "something"+id and the value being a serialized json object.
2. I would like to be able to get list of the above objects in a paged manner, say first page, and page size is 20. (Hashset or Sorted Set)
3. number 2 above Can also be done with paging but filtered by one of the fields first then return results

I would like to only have one copy of each json object to satisfy the above scenarios, from everything I read so far it seems that I will be creating multiple copies of each object to satisfy all of the above scenarios.

So in short, I like my list of objects stored to be retrieved by a

1. Retrieve a single item by an ID (property of the json object
2. Paged lists without filters
3. Paged lists with paging and filtering of json objects
4. At any time any of the event objects can be changed by the user, so the cache needs to be updated (invalidate cache/update cache)

I am writing the code in .NET so if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure Redis is the best tool for the job? Redis is primarily a key/value store. Filtering on values is not its strong suit by any means. Why are you wanting to use Redis for this over some sort of database that’s designed to do filtering and pagination? I wouldn’t personally use Redis for this, which is probably why you’re having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Comment: @nate I am already using a RDBM, I am introducing possibly using Redis to offload the work from the db server and make queries faster as its in memory retrieval vs having to go to the db.  I am also questioning if the filtering part should be part of Redis, but I would like to at least get the paging and single item retrieval working if possible with reds

Comment: If I were you, I’d see if there is any performance tuning you can do to your database. Perhaps maybe you’re missing some key indices or something. This kind of stuff should be lightning fast even with an RDBM. If it’s not, you probably have a database problem that should be fixed instead of ignored. I know that doesn’t answer your question here, but I think it’s the best approach.

Comment: Also, I would examine the queries you’re running. Sometimes people run not very good queries and then are surprised when they’re slow.

Comment: @Nate Thanks for the replies, the queries are very lightweight and will be tuned to hell with indexes and such. The idea of introducing Redis is purely as another option if and when the tuning and indexes on the db are not good enough and Redis can be turned on and off.  My past experiences says that in-memory (not Redis) cache can be lightening faster than the most tuned db in most cases but never done the actual paging/filtering against the in-mem objects.  This is a new territory for me hence why I am exploding more options.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, good luck to you!

Comment: I would look into MongoDB or ElasticSearch instead of Redis for your search index needs. Redis is a great key value store, but not great at searching. But know that keeping your Primary Data Store (your RDBM) and Search Index (Redis, Mongo, ES, etc) in sync is a very large job. So you only want to go down that route if you really really need to. Problems you’ll face are timing issues which result in some pages displaying one thing and other pages displaying something else, and needing to totally reindex when you want to change your data in the search index.

Comment: I would also see where you’re bottleneck is. In the past I’ve had trouble (in a Ruby system) with JSON serialization. My queries are fast, but serializing to JSON was slow. Switching libraries for serialization helped substantially.

Comment: I plan on actually doing some performance testing with key/pair with redis and deserilzation vs direct db calls and will add more info to this question once that's done, I really have no bottlenecks at this point, I am purely doing this in case db becomes a bottleneck and having redis to be turned on and off will definitely be a plus if bottlenecks are introduced but first and most is to do some performance tests

Comment: Nice! Well, I hope my comments were helpful in your testing and research.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like on top of doing simple key value queries, what you need it some additional logic to run on the server (Redis) side. You can use Lua scripts in Redis to perform such tasks.

If I understand your requirements correctly, here is how I'd approach:

1. Store objects in a sorted set (if you the returned objects in a specific order)
2. You can now querying single and unfiltered objects by native Redis commands:
   [Redis - Sorted set, find item by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854616/redis-sorted-set-find-item-by-property-value)
3. For filtered objects you can look into Lua scripts
4. Redis does not provide anything out of the box to invalidate/update cache stored in lists. And you'll have to write additional code to handle cache updation. Read more here: https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis

You can also check ignite, it has a couple of features built in that may be of interest to you:

1. Binary marshaller :
   "It enables you to read an arbitrary field from an object's serialized form without full object deserialization."
   https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller
2. Read/Write through ability for cache updation: https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/caching/database-caching.html